# Extensions of infinite loop spaces

Tags: homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

I've been reading Rognes' paper "[Algebraic K-theory of 2-adic integers](https://folk.uio.no/rognes/papers/twoadic.pdf)" and I'm confused about something he's doing regarding infinite loop spaces (see Theorem 8.1 of that paper). Let me try to phrase more generally what confuses me:

Suppose we have a fiber sequence of connective spectra
$X\to Y\to Z$. We can think of $Y$ as an extension of $Z$ by $X$ in some sense and (supposedly) the homotopy type of $Y$ is determined by maps of spectra $\Sigma^{-1}Z\to X$.

Why is this the case? Is there an analog of this in the world of group extensions? I've never seen a result like this before and I haven't been able to figure myself why it should be true. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Because the stable homotopy category is triangulated, and a fiber sequence is in particular a distinguished triangle in that category; with that in mind the result follows from a general result in triangulated categories ($\Sigma^{-1}Z\to X\to Y \to Z$ is a distinguished triangle, so the isomorphism type of $Y$ is determined by the map $\Sigma^{-1}Z\to X$). You can think of it via the long exact sequence you get when applying $\hom(x,-)$

Comment: Think about chain complexes instead of group extensions. What does the shifted sequence look like for the exact sequence of complexes $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z \to (\Bbb Z/2)$?

Comment: Puppe showed that the homotopy fiber of $X \to Y$ is $\Sigma^{-1} Z$, and the homotopy cofiber of $Y \to Z$ is $\Sigma X$, so that $Y$ can be recovered as the homotopy cofiber of $\Sigma^{-1} Z \to X$, or as the homotopy fiber of $Z \to \Sigma X$:
$$\Sigma^{-1} Z \to X \to Y \to Z \to \Sigma X$$
If $X = HA$, $Y = HB$, $Z = HC$ are Eilenberg-Mac Lane spectra, then you have a short exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$, and the homotopy class of $Z \to \Sigma X$ in $[Z, \Sigma X]_{H\mathbb{Z}-mod}$ corresponds to a class in $Ext^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(C, A)$ that classifies this extension.

Comment: @JohnRognes Ok that clarifies things a lot. It's even easier than I was thinking. Thanks!